# How to find VPC id's from all accounts in AWS control tower organization

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

We have multiple (more than 100) aws accounts created using Control tower account factory. Each account have configured with VPC's.

Is there any way to list VPC id's from all these accounts centrally ?

Login to each account and listing vpc id's will not be working with too many accounts.

Answer (score 2):

If you login to the Control Tower audit account, you can use AWS Config queries to find this information.

Navigate to AWS Config > Advanced Queries.
Under Query Scope, select the aws-controltower-ComplianceGuardrailsAggregator

For a query enter:

```
SELECT resourceId WHERE resourceType = 'AWS::EC2::VPC'
```